# Sort JavaScript object by length of array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have an object like this:

```
var list = {
  "you": [100,200,300], 
  "me": [75,4,5,6,8,9], 
  "foo": [116,345,1,23,56,78], 
  "bar": [15,34]
};
```

Is there any way to `sort` this object by the length of the array properties?

Expected output:

```
var res =  [[116,345,1,23,56,78],[75,4,5,6,8,9],[100,200,300],[15,34]]
```

I tried using lodash's `sortby` function.

```js
var data = {
  "abc": ["20288", "d8f0", "4a5d", "1a8a0"],
  "kkl": ["bnb", "lll", "zxc"],
  "F17": ["ee547", "42e9"],
  "cnv": ["20288", "d8f0", "4a5d", "1a8a0", "jh67"]
}

var res = _.sortBy(data, function(val) {
  return parseInt(val.length);
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have create a snippet from your fiddle. Please read: [How do I create a stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want the output as an array of sorted array values:

   Use **[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)** to get the `length` property from the resulting array by calling `Object.values` and then sort it in descending order.

```js
const data = {
  "abc": ["20288", "d8f0", "4a5d", "1a8a0"],
  "kkl": ["bnb", "lll", "zxc"],
  "F17": ["ee547", "42e9"],
  "cnv": ["20288", "d8f0", "4a5d", "1a8a0", "jh67"]
};
const res = Object.values(data).sort(({length:a}, {length:b}) => b - a);
console.log(res);
```

---

2. If you want to sort the object itself by re-arranging the keys as per the length of array values.

   > Is there any way to sort this object by the length of the array
   >   properties?

   If you want to re-arrange the original object properties as per the `length` of the array values, then we first need to sort by the keys and then create a **new** **object** with the sorted order of the keys utilizing **[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**.

```js
const data = {
  "abc": ["20288", "d8f0", "4a5d", "1a8a0"],
  "kkl": ["bnb", "lll", "zxc"],
  "F17": ["ee547", "42e9"],
  "cnv": ["20288", "d8f0", "4a5d", "1a8a0", "jh67"]
};
//sorting in descending order
const obj = Object.keys(data)
                  .sort((a, b) => data[b].length - data[a].length )
                  .reduce((acc, ele) => { acc[ele] = data[ele]; return acc; }, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @Eswar, Glad to help buddy, please accept my answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** to get the values in an array and then [**`sort`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the resulting 2D array based on the `length` like this:

```js
var data = {
  "abc": ["20288", "d8f0", "4a5d", "1a8a0"],
  "kkl": ["bnb", "lll", "zxc"],
  "F17": ["ee547", "42e9"],
  "cnv": ["20288", "d8f0", "4a5d", "1a8a0", "jh67"]
}

const res = Object.values(data).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
console.log(res)
```